# Wifi card can see network but cannot connect

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, drivers

I just installed Ubuntu 12.04 on a Toshiba Satellite. I am able to see many wireless networks, but I am not able to connect. Here is the output of various commands that found looking for existing answers.

`lshw -C network`:

```
*-network
  description: Wireless Interface
  product: AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express)
  vendor: Atheros Communications Inc.
  ....
```

`lscpi -k`:

```
...
03:00.0 Network Controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Expres) (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Askey Computer Corp Device 7159
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
    Kernel modules: ath9k
```

(Other entries do not contain the word Wire.)

`rfkill list`:

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
```

I saw a recommendation to add `blacklist acer_wmi` to `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`, but that did not change anything.

I've run out of ideas as to why it isn't working. The driver appears to be installed and it can even see the network. It is even making repeated attempts to connect to it, but it is failing.

I've also tried connecting to an unsecured network, which also fails. However, as all I know is that it was an unsecured 'linksys' network which might be doing something like MAC filtering, that is not very useful evidence.

EDIT: After waiting an hour or so, it connected without any intervention on my part.  I then downloaded all of the updates and rebooted.  The wifi connection was there for the hour of downloading.

I then rebooted, since the updates required it.  It now is back to not connecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually configured the network with static information instead of querying the DHCP server.  That fixed the problem, although a static configuration raises other problems (address collisions, address changes).